# "ERROR Failed to write log event to MongoDB due to invalid result [0]" when using NoSQLAppender

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I get following message

```
ERROR Failed to write log event to MongoDB due to invalid result [0]
```

when using NoSQLAppender with log4j2 v2.0-beta8

Despite th error the log event gets written to MongoDB. Do you know how to suppress it ?

Here is my config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
    <appenders>
        <NoSql name="databaseAppender" suppressExceptions="true">
            <MongoDb collectionName="applicationLog" factoryClassName="com.borsch.DBManager" factoryMethodName="getNewMongoClient" writeConcernConstant="NONE" username="root" password="qwe"/>
        </NoSql>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

What's even more strange I can't find the code that generates it. I didn't find such string in sources of log4j2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to maintainers and it was fixed.